# How to fix Unexpected token 'export' ' in line export class ReusableRay

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently, I want to use a Three.js and detect clicked object to get information about this object.

So, I see this example: [sample](https://jensarps.de/2012/08/10/mouse-picking-collada-models-with-three-js/) 
It's using a [ReusableRay](https://github.com/jensarps/webgl_experiments/blob/master/ReusableRay.js)  class, but my current javascript project is inside of  .

I am trying to adapt a module: [my example Project](https://github.com/manujose94/Visualizador)

```
  <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './js/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import {ReusableRay } from './js/ReusableRay.js'; // error
        //detect
        if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        var ray = new ReusableRay();
        var projector = new THREE.Projector();
        var directionVector = new THREE.Vector3();
```

But I always have the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'. This is my modified class: [myReusableRay](https://github.com/manujose94/Visualizador/blob/master/js/ReusableRay.js)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.html` you include `ReusableRay` twice. One time via the `<script>` tag and then with an ES6 `import` statement. Since `ReusableRay` is a module, you can only use ES6 imports.

BTW: You also include `three.js` twice. One time `three.js` with `<script>` and then via ES6 imports `import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';`. This is definitely wrong. In general, you should avoid mixing modules vs. non-module code.

I also suggest you study more closely how ES6 modules work in order to avoid such issues.

https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html